# Make a select show the currently selected option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, highlight

I'm using rails and have this code:

```
<%= select_tag :tag, options_for_select(["Politics", "Technology", "Entertainment", 
   "Sports", "Science", "Crime", "Business", "Social", "Nature", "Other"]), :selected => 
    "Politics" %>
```

The `:selected` part is apparently not a valid option, but it relays what I wish to do. In place of `"Politics"` should be the currently selected option (I know how to do this part). But more importantly, what is the option to default highlight a select option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default selected option is stated in the option_for_select method

The second attribute the method accepts is which element should be selected.

```
options_for_select(container, selected = nil)
```

So in your case, the code would be:

```
<%= select_tag :tag, options_for_select(["Politics", "Technology", "Entertainment", 
   "Sports", "Science", "Crime", "Business", "Social", "Nature", "Other"], "Politics") %>
```